# React Native Android [AxiosError: Network Error]

Tags: react-native, axios

My React Native project was successfully running on both Android and iOS.
But suddenly it http request failed on Android.
It's still working find on iOS.
When I change the domain to ip address it works fine on Android.
Why does this happen?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjeQt.png)

I tried to add content-type to request headers like below but still get the same results.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LOBz.png)

Comment: PS. I updated SSL certificate and after that the above error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
Below link helped me.
https://community.f5.com/t5/technical-forum/ssl-handshake-failed-for-tcp-android-application-request/td-p/312099

I didn't install chain certificate correctly, so handshake was failed in android.
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Installed chain certificate and it worked well.